# How do I disable a button based on multiple states in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a form with React and I wanted to disable a button when the form is not 'valid', i.e. when one of the states is blank. The button looks at a state called `disable_button`. Here's what I have so far:

```
var MyForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      group_id: '',
      ls_type_id: '',
      disable_button: false
    };
  },
  handleGroupChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({group_id: e.target.value});
  },
  handleTypeChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({ls_type_id: e.target.value});
  },
  handleClick: function() {
    console.log('Button clicked');
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.isFormValid();
  },
  isFormValid: function(){
    if (this.state.group_id == '' || this.state.ls_type_id == '') {
      this.setState({disable_button: true});
    } else {
      this.setState({disable_button: false});
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select className='form-control' value={this.state.group_id} onChange={this.handleGroupChange}>
          <option value=''>Select group...</option>
          <option value='10'>Some group</option>
        </select>
        <br /> 
        <select className='form-control' value={this.state.ls_type_id} onChange={this.handleTypeChange}>
          <option value=''>Select type...</option>
          <option value='11'>Some type</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick} disabled={this.state.disable_button}>Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Running this code results in an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` and I realize why: it's because after the component updates, it calls my `componentDidUpdate`, which then updates a state, which then updates the component, and the loop occurs. So I don't really know how can I make the button disable when one of those states is blank. I might add more form fields so I didn't want to hardcode it to only look at these two selects.

Comment: Just call the `isFormValid` method in the change handlers. You don't need a `componentDidUpdate` method.

Comment: Any value that _can_ be calculated during render, _should_ be calculated during render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` has two props passed in to it, `prevProps` and `prevState` as [documented](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate). You could use this fact in `componentUpdate` to only call `isFormValid` if either the `type_id` or `ls_type_id` has changed.

However, the cascading setState calls are a little inefficient. It might make more sense to determine `disable_button` in your render function, since you don't appear to be consuming it anywhere else. So, delete `isFormValid` and all calls to it, and put this in the beginning of render:

```
render: function () {
  var disable_button = false;
  if (this.state.group_id == '' || this.state.ls_type_id == '') {
    disable_button = true;
  }
  return ( <div> ...content </div>
}
```

Comment: Okay yeah that makes sense, follows what [@Dan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402274/how-do-i-disable-a-button-based-on-multiple-states-in-react/39402358#comment66130533_39402274) mentioned in his comment too. I just had the mind set of 'make things that can get disabled/enabled a state'.

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
isFormValid: function(){
  return this.state.group_id == '' || this.state.ls_type_id == '';
}
```

...

```
<button disabled={this.isFormValid()} ...>
```

Comment: Yeah basically same as the other answer. I'll use this in my code.